# Get URL from InputStream

Tags: java, stream, java-io

I'm wondering how **InputStream** in java is implemented from low level perspective.

Suppose I write a below java code for making connection with a website.

```
url = new URL("[some url info]");
URLConnection urlcon = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = urlcon.getInputStream();
while((readcount = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        fos.write(buffer,0,readcount);
```

Could I know URL from InputStream("in" in the above code block) directly by casting it's type and call an appropriate method like below? Are there any other ways to get URL from InputStream?

```
(newtype) new = (newtype) in;
String Url = new.appropriatemethod();
```

I searched all subclasses of InputStream, but I couldn't find any classes which have a interface to give it's URL. 
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

However, I think InputStream somehow have information of URL to receive data from a website which has this URL.

I might have big misunderstanding about "Stream".

Thank you for reading my quetion. :)

Comment: why do you want to call the method to get the url, when you have the url.""[some url info]""

Comment: Are you talking about webservice?

Comment: @karman No, it's just java I/O. I agree it seems strange to get URL from "in" instead of "url". However, I got stuck into a situation which I should get URL from "in", and I want to know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: You have url object(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), if you want any kind of information about url. InputStream is just a stream of response, you won't get that from it, unless it is provided in the response body. You can look for response headers(http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/)

Comment: @karman I got your point partially. When we type like "in.read ()" it reads response from a website, so isn't "in" should know basic info (like URL or Sokect (which might have URL)) to get data from a destination (website). Or other objects put data into the stream? Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputStream` is just a [stream](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/input_stream.shtml) not a `URLConnection`. When you type `InputStream in = urlcon.getInputStream();` . You will get input stream not a url connection. When you type `in.read` then you are reading the Stream and not `URLConnection`.

> An InputStream is a reference to source of data (be it a file, network
> connection etc), that we want to process as follows:
>
> - we generally want to read the data as "raw bytes" and then write our own code to do something interesting with the bytes;
> - we generally want to read the data in sequential order: that is, to get to the nth byte of data, we have to read all the preceding bytes first, and we're not guaranteed to be able to "jump back" again once we've read them.